# Eclipse scout Neon disabled only one row in table

Tags: row, isenabled, eclipse-scout

I would like to disable only one `row` in `Table`.

So after performing some action I would like to disabled one row. (I have table that is editable and "disabled" row for me mean that I can't change value)

```
row.setEnabled(false);
```

does not work, because it disable whole table.

---

Edit :

I actually need enabling/ disabling cells in rows.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out.

Interfaces of row and cell doesn't have this specification, but if you use method

```
@Override
protected void execDecorateCell(final Cell view, final ITableRow row, final IColumn<?> col) {

  super.execDecorateCell(view, row, col);

  // set cell editable.
  view.setEditable(false);
}
```

And this disable specific row from editing.

If you would like to disable specific row, you could limit it by `row` and `col`.
So you can disable really specific cell. Don't forget to add

```
else {
    view.setEditable(true);
}
```

so when this method is called again it will update old cells (if they maybe are enabled this time).